# Protractor + Safari non-secure form warning

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, safari, protractor, alert

**os:** `OS X El Capitan`

**node:**`v5.4.1`

**protractor:** `3.3`

**safari:** `9.0.3`

I'm getting a security warning popup in in my test and I was wondering if there is a way to get around it in any fashion. The popup security warning doesn't seem to come up on chrome and `browser.switchTo().alert();` doesn't seem to work?

this is what the alert/security warning looks like

[image]

Apparently they block mixed content and it doesn't seem like there is an option anymore to change

[Why is mixed content blocked in Safari](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7235380?start=0&tstart=0)

I have tried to press Tab then Enter b/c that works manually but it seems to give an error when i use this code

```
browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.TAB).sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();
```

`Failed: Unknown command: {"id":"z4v9sab7uay","name":"sendKeysToActiveElement","parameters":{"value":[""]}} (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)`

Comment: Could you please check if you have the same problem with safari 9.1?

Comment: @alecxe I apologize that I didn't have the latest version. I don't use safari if I don't have to and apparently wasn't up to date. I updated my safari to Version 9.1.1 (11601.6.17). I guess there is an option to disable the security check locally but the end goal is to run the tests on browserstack and I'm not sure if that's something that can be done